# Throwing ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, django, django-models, annotations, django-orm

I need to get a calculation of some data so, in annotate I put some maths logic with other field but whenever there is 0 it is throwing an error. I need to handle that error in annotate. My code looks like this:

```
total_amount = Invoice.objects.filter(client_account__account_UID=account_UID,
                                              created_at__range=(from_date, to_date)
                                              ).aggregate(Sum('total_amount'))['total_amount__sum']

total_billable_leads = CampaignContact.objects.filter(campaign=campaigns, billable=True, billable_item__created_at__range=(from_date, to_date)).count()

cch = CampaignContactHistory.objects.annotate(
            campaign_name=F('campaign__name')
                 ).values('campaign_name'
                 ).filter(id__in=cch_ids
                 ).annotate(
            total=Count('lead_status'),
            scheduled=Count(Case(When(lead_status='10', then=1))),
            total_billable=(int(total_amount) / total_billable_leads) * Count(Case(When(campaign_contact__billable=True, then=1))),
        )
```

In total_billable, there is `total_billable_leads` variable which may have Zero(0) then on a division it will throw an error. So, please help me to handle this exception in annotate.

**CampaignContactHistory Model**

```
class CampaignContactHistory(DateAwareModel):
    campaign_contact = models.ForeignKey(CampaignContact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lead_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=leadstatus, default=FRESH)
    campaigner = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    response_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    first_reponse = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    second_reponse = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, null=True, blank=True)
```

For result I want if it is an error or zero(0) it should return zero(0) otherwise the calculated value.

Comment: what result do you want? remove this records or may be divide by 1?

Comment: If it is zero(0) or error then it should return Zero only

Comment: please add model and maybe some lines to create instances

Comment: ```CampaignContactHistory``` this model you want?

Comment: yes i mean the `CampaignContactHistory`

Comment: @BearBrown.. model added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172045/discussion-between-shubham-srivastava-and-bear-brown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `total_amount` and `total_billable_leads` are constants so you get the error on python level, so the solution is:

```
if total_billable_leads:
    total_amount_avg = int(total_amount) / total_billable_leads
else:
    total_amount_avg = 0

cch = CampaignContactHistory.objects.annotate(
            campaign_name=F('campaign__name')
                 ).values('campaign_name'
                 ).filter(id__in=cch_ids
                 ).annotate(
            total=Count('lead_status'),
            scheduled=Count(Case(When(lead_status='10', then=1))),
            total_billable=total_amount_avg * Count(Case(When(campaign_contact__billable=True, then=1))),
            #               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        )
```

Comment: and what is your `total_amount`?  constant

Comment: it's integer coming from sperate query

Comment: ohhh....!! what a simple logic... how can miss that..!! Thanks alot..... :)

Comment: sometimes it happens), glad to help you!